# Maxima and minima of area under graph for concave up function

Tags: calculus

Let f be a function such that f"(x) exists, and f"(x) > 0 for all
x ∈ [a, b]. For any point c ∈ [a, b], let A(c) denote the area of the
region bounded by y = f(x), the tangent to the graph of f at x = c and the lines x = a and x = b. Then

(A) A(c) attains its minimum at $c =\frac{1}{2} (a + b)$ for any such f

(B) A(c) attains its maximum at $c =\frac{1}{2} (a + b)$ for any such f

(C) A(c) attains its minimum at both c = a and c = b for any such f

(D) the points c where A(c) attains its minimum depend on f.

My approach is $$A(c)=\int\limits_a^b (f(x)-f(c)-f'(c)\cdot(x-c))dx,$$

$ \Rightarrow A'(c)=-\int\limits_a^b (f''(c)\cdot(x-c))dx$

$ A'(c)=0 \Rightarrow c=\frac{1}{2}(a+b)$

Now at A'(c) sign of derivative changes from - to +, so it should be a point of minima

I just wish to be sure if I have done it correctly

Comment: I don’t understand your description of the area as for a convex functions, a tangent to the graph is below the graph itself.

Comment: Your results are correct. But how do you justify differentiating under the integral sign (which presumably is what you've done for $A'(c)$)? One way would be to use that $f''$ is continuous but we don't know that here. To avoid this issue, I would instead compute $A'(c)$ directly from $A(c)$.